# How to combine react-i18next with Semantic UI label tag?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, material-ui, react-i18next

I am using Semantic UI with the combination of [react-i18next][2] and need to make label string **translatable**, but this label has a HTML tag in it, for example `span`. However, it only accepts string which is hardcoded or variable.

Answer (score 1):

## This is not possible

The props for the FormControlLabel state that the label prop is `The text to be used in an enclosing label element.`

Check it [here](https://material-ui.com/api/form-control-label/#formcontrollabel-api)

You will have to make a custom label control for this element or extend `FormControlLabel` (highly suggest you don't extend)

### Custom Label

Put your checkbox in as children add it should work, but you need to expand on the controls.

```
const CustomLabel = (props) => (
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: t('login.accept')}} />
)

// implementation

<CustomLable />
<Checkbox />
```

### Workaround

What you could do is strip the tags from your strings so that you get the plain text.

`cleanText = strInputCode.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");`

Comment: Thanks. Can you please provide an example of custom label control and I will mark your answer as helpful? Also, why you don't suggest extending it?

Comment: hey, extending classes in react is an anti pattern (I think) and not really used although it is possible. Thought I would mention it.

Comment: stripping tags removes your <span> tag from the string but you loose the styling with it as well

Comment: I need styling... is there a better way instead of using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` ?

Comment: haha yeah the name is triggering. I don't think so, since you have a string and want it to be html you need to do it this way to keep the styles.

Comment: Please provide working example with my code.. thanks.